# Sudden exception during UDP streaming

Tags: network-programming, udp, video-streaming

I have an open UDP connection that streams video for several hours between two machines on different vlans.
After several hours I get the following exception on the server side (the transmitter):

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A blocking operation was
>   interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
>   size, SocketFlags socketFlags)

From that moment on, from time to time (not on every send), I see the following:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A non-blocking socket operation
>   could not be completed immediately    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
>   size, SocketFlags socketFlags)

On the client side I see no exception or abnormal behavior.

Is it possible that I get this exception due to a N/W problem, for example, something in the switch?
Any other ideas what can cause these exceptions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will make a wild guess about WSACancelBlockingCall exception.

Probably you are trying to **close** the socket from another thread or your socket is getting disposed somehow with garbage collector.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did a massive code review and for sure I have only one thread that work with this socket. This is why I tend to think that maybe the problem is in the network.